# Android Studio: Dependencies not included in Java module using Gradle 4.1

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a Java module that generates some metadata for my Android app and needs to run as a regular Java application. After updating to Android Studio 3.0 (in 2.3.3 it worked as expected) I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the dependencies (in the case below for `com/google/gson/GsonBuilder`, the `main` method itself can be found).

I even tried putting the GSON Jar into the `libs` folder but it still throws the `NoClassDefFoundError`.

I assume the dependencies are not properly included. Any idea how to fix this?

The `build.gradle` looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

My class looks like this:

```
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class myClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think in your build.gradle file where you have `apply plugin: 'java'`, you can't use `'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'` dependency. It can only be used in those `build.gradle` file where the plugin is `application` or `library`. That's why you get `NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: It worked before in AS 2.3.3... I also tried changing `apply plugin: 'java'` to `apply plugin: 'java-library'` with no success...

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"`?. Android studio 3.0 supports Java 1.8 by default. So I guess remove these two lines might work for you.

Comment: I've tried both, removing it and setting it to 1.8 - still no success...

Comment: I am having the same issue with Android 3.0. It happens with any library from maven and also using Java 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Use `api` instead of `implementation`.

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations)

> When your module configures an implementation dependency, it's
> letting Gradle know that the module does not want to leak the
> dependency to other modules at compile time. That is, the dependency
> is available to other modules only at runtime.
>
> Using this dependency
> configuration instead of api or compile can result in significant
> build time improvements because it reduces the amount of projects that
> the build system needs to recompile. For example, if an implementation
> dependency changes its API, Gradle recompiles only that dependency and
> the modules that directly depend on it. Most app and test modules
> should use this configuration.

See [difference between api and implementation here](https://blog.mindorks.com/implementation-vs-api-in-gradle-3-0-494c817a6fa) for more info.

Comment: Thanks! I noticed that `api` does not work with `apply plugin: 'java'`. When I use `apply plugin: 'java-library'` instead `api` works, but still gives me the above exception...

Comment: @jeff_bordon if possible try to convert that java library to an android library, by that way you will be able to manage you dependencies in a better way in `build.gradle` of the library. The thing is that with the new update of gradle there is some restriction on the availability of a dependency to other modules to improve build time.

Comment: Thanks, using an Android library works - however, it feels strange misusing a console application as android library. There must be a way to have java programs with dependencies run from Android Studio using Gradle...

Comment: I am having the same problem. It doen't mattter if I use "java" or "java-library" and "api" or "implementation". I just create a new module with Android Studio 3.0 and write Gson gson = new Gson and it gives the error. It happens with every library, not only Gson. Also, I can't use an Android Library because I need to use the library in a backend Java module.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem probably related with Android Gradle plug-in. Try using `compile` instead of `implementation in your`build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = "1.7"
targetCompatibility = "1.7"
```

The above is working in Android Studio 3.0 but with Android Gradle plug-in 2.3.3 in root build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

---

**UPDATE**

I manage to make it works by adding `google()` to repositories block in **root** `build.gradle`. The following build.gradle is for the Java module:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'

}

sourceCompatibility = "1.8"
targetCompatibility = "1.8"
```

And this is my root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
    classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.7.3'
    classpath 'com.github.dcendents:android-maven-gradle-plugin:1.5'
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
}
```

Tested on Android Studio 3.0 with **Gradle 4.1**.

Comment: Thanks! When I switch back to Gradle plugin 2.3.3 and Gradle distribution version 3.3 and apply `compile` instead of `implementation` it works... However, I need to use the newest versions (3.0.0 and Gradle 4.1)... Any idea how to make it work there?

Comment: Thanks! However, I was unable to make it work, I even created a completely new project from the "New Project" dialog and added your files. Have you made it work with a new project?

Comment: I don't test it with a new project yet. I'm testing it with my library.

Comment: @jeff_bordon: I've created a new project and adding a java module. It's work for me.

Comment: Thanks, investigating further why it does not work... very strange

Comment: @jeff_bordon: This is the project I've created with java module: https://github.com/isnotmenow/JavaPluginTest

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158768/discussion-between-jeff-bordon-and---).

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך In that project you forgot to use a method from Gson. If you add "    Gson gson = new Gson();" it doesn't work because of the same issue